# How can I access Amazon DynamoDB via Python?

Tags: python, database, nosql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm currently using hbase with my Python apps and wanted to try out Amazon [DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/). Is there a way to use Python to read, write and query data?

Comment: Is there any abstraction layer that supports DynamoDB as well as other NoSQL databases?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use boto3: https://github.com/boto/boto3

docs: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html

api reference: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html

Answer (score 28):

Another alternative is [PynamoDB](http://pynamodb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). PynamoDB provides an ORM like interface to DynamoDB and supports **both** Python 2 and Python 3. The entire DynamoDB API is supported by PynamoDB - including global and local secondary indexes, batch operations, binary attributes, queries, scans, etc.

Disclaimer: I wrote PynamoDB.

Comment: As of the time of this comment DAX isn't supported by PynamoDB. Hopefully the pull requests that adds support for it will be added at some point, but right now I'm having to use boto3 and make all the queries by hand with amazon-dax-client.

Comment: Wow - PynamoDB is awesome!

Answer (score 14):

Disclaimer: I'm the current maintainer

You can use [Dynamodb-mapper](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dynamodb-mapper) Python library. It's a simple/tiny abstraction layer that allows you to **map plain Python object to DynamoDB**. It also features a transaction engine.

For advanced tasks such as table management it is still better to directly use [Boto](https://github.com/boto/boto) (which we rely on, anyway).

Answer (score 3):

This question has been years so I believe your problem was already resolved. Just want to mention that you could use [boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html) to access DynamoDB as well nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of Lucid-Dynamodb, a minimalist wrapper to AWS DynamoDB. It covers all the Dynamodb operations.

**Reference:** https://github.com/dineshsonachalam/Lucid-Dynamodb